# Dealing with and sign in goal

Tags: coq, coqide

I have a goal in my coq and there is "&" sign in it. How can I deal with it?

I appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: Can you post the specific example? Without context it is almost impossible to help. That said, when dealing with unknown notations you may try `Locate "&"`, and / or `Unset Printing Notations`.

Comment: It's quite likely the notation of an existential packaging, but it would indeed helped if you gave details. In case that's correct, you could deal with it by providing a witness via `exists <your_witness>.`, which would leave you with a goal like `P <your_witness>` where `P` is the property you're trying to provide an existential proof of.